# Apache server on Rackspace (cloud) server

Tags: apache, rackspace

I am trying to shift from django web development server to Apache server. The website is hosted on rackspace server which i am accessing using ssh. I have installed apache on the server.

Now the problem is even if I edit apache conf files, changes are not being reflected in response to client requests. Is it like the rackspace server I am using, is having a system wide default implementation of Apache? If yes, how do I access that instance? I checked in file system but it only contains apache which I have installed.

More surprisingly even when apache(my installation) service is not running, still "It Works" page is received from server.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is even if I edit apache conf files, changes are not
>   being reflected in response to client requests.

It isn't enough to simply edit the configuration files. Many web frameworks (like Django) automatically reload when you change your source code or configuration, but with "production" web servers like Apache or Nginx, you'll need to restart the server to pick up changes. Generally you do so with a command like:

```
# Debian or Ubuntu image:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

# Redhat or CentOS image:
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

You can also tell Apache to reload its configuration *without* fully turning off and back on again, which is nicer once you have traffic coming to your site:

```
# Debian or Ubuntu image:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

# Redhat or CentOS image:
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd graceful
```

> More surprisingly even when apache (my installation) service is not running, still "It Works" page is received from server.

Are you sure that the service has been stopped successfully? You can check by searching for the process with the `ps` command:

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

And also by seeing which process is listening on port 80 or 443 with `netstat`:

```
sudo netstat -n -l -p | grep 80
```

Once you've found the process ID, you can `kill` it:

```
sudo kill 12345

# And if that doesn't work:
sudo kill -9 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

As an add-on, to find the process id that apache is running on you can run:

```
$ lsof -i:80
```

or/and

```
$ lsof -i:443
```

If the `lsof` executable is not there:

Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lsof
```

CentOS/RedHat

```
$ sudo yum install lsof
```

You generally want to run lsof as `root` otherwise you will get several "permission denied" lines.